# How does Gmap.net cache works?

Tags: c#, caching, gmap.net

I´m using the GMAP.net library in a project and I found it was a powerful tool. It´s cache facility made it a real profit to my project. Anyway, I need if someone can tell me a little bit of how that cache works. As far as I tested it, I can see that it pre-allocates space (in my case about 200 mb on SQLITE file), so I started doing some test seeing how it worked, and it turns out it works really well, but in some cases I have been viewing maps that haven´t been cached. I don´t know if I have to spent some time with the position on the map so It can be cached or something like that. Does the tile cache file size increases with the time?, or it just keeps the prealocated size?.

Thanks in advance for any possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been doing some research on this same topic. I learned that the application by default has a gmdb of 256mb. This doesnt mean that there is 256mb of cached map. It just creates room for the cache data. Look at this post by Radio man for more clarity. Hope this helps. If you find more info post if for others because there is a lot of missing info on this topic.

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/274628

Comment: Thanks man. I´ve already asked this to radioman... here is the answer https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/457064